# DateTime conversion exception

Tags: c#, datetime

This is code

```
String date = "1980/1/1"; 
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/DD", null);
// I have also tried 
// DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/DD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and this is Exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

**Update**

Getting same error using following code

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/M/D", null);
```

Comment: Use lower case `d` , not the upper case `D`

Comment: the `D` must NOT be capital => `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/M/d", null);`

Comment: You need to use "M" for month and "d" for day not big "D"...try solution given in my answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (tested)

```
String date = "1980/1/1";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy'/'M'/'d",null);
```

the character slash is between single qoutation.

Answer (score 2):

use single `M` and Single `d`

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/M/d", null);
```

Single `M` will take care for month `01`, `1` to `12`, similarly Single `d` will take care of day from `1` to `31`, including `01` to `09`

You may see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

use only `yyyy/M/D`. it threw an exception because it is expecting `yyyy/01/01` two digits for month and day.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/M/d", null);
```

Comment: i think this should be yyyy/M/D like this yyyy/M/d